# Android Floating Action Button Semi Transparent Background Color

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I want to use FAB with semi transparent background color.
But I am getting a FAB with two different colors. What's the problem?

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#99f03456"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

[image]

And without any drawable.

[image]

Comment: try to create this color in your `color.xml` and use `app:backgroundTint="@color/yourcolor"`

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>  define your color to style theme in your project

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid no difference.

Comment: @MohammedSameerAhmad not working.

Comment: try to delete your background drawable and see what will happen

Comment: @MohammedSameerAhmad no difference.

Comment: I think you should file an issue.

Comment: I think i should too :D.

Answer (score 22):

Set elevation and pressedTranslationZ zero to remove the effects

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickMyLocation"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/transparentColor"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_location"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 19):

Got the same issue here.
I tried to set alpha transparency in xml using backgroundTint but it didn't work and resulted in the same appearance as in your screenshots (two circles).

So I set it in code like this :

```
floatingButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
floatingButton.setAlpha(0.25f);
```

And the look is now consistent.

Comment: it works, but this also makes the icon transparent ... :-/

Answer (score 10):

Unless the elevation is necessary, you can remove the "inner circle" by setting it to 0:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

As @David notes in the comments, you may want to try 1dp if 0 does not work.

Comment: I have the same issue, but only `app:elevation="1dp"` helped. 0 hides the FAB at all

Comment: I'm guessing it depends on different themes, APIs/SDKs, and all that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using Jerzy Chalupski floating action button:
https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

To use in your project add:

```
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
```

to your dependencies,

and then add:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/my_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="myMethod"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/my_icon"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/my_transparent_color"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white"
            />
```

into your XML file.

It works